# How to apply style to specific item in the array iterating using *ngFor when on click in Ionic using Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework, ngfor, ionic5

I'm trying to apply styling for a specific item in the iterable array when on click. The problem I'm facing is, it applies the style to the whole items in the array.

I want to apply the style dynamically only to that particular index when the button is clicked.

Below are excerpts from my code

**HTML file**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let car of cars; let i=index;" #item>
    <ion-item [ngStyle]="car.sold || isSold ? {color: 'red'} : ''">
      <ion-label>{{car.name}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options icon-start>
      <button ion-button (click)="markAsSold(car, i, item)">
          Mark as Sold
        </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

**TS file**

```
isSold = false; 

markAsSold(car, index, item){
  this.isSold = !car.sold;
  item.close();
}
```

I have created a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-huhhra?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) using Stackblitz. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by attributing `this.isSold` and verifying `car.sold || isSold` it will return `isSold` wich is a global value to every item.

You should verify the `ngStyle` without `isSold`, your sold logic should be attributed only for a specific item, if you change the flag: `car.sold = !car.sold`, and the `ngStyle` as `car.sold ? {color: 'red'} : ''`

Comment: Thank you but that did not work. Could you please show it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-huhhra?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6gw4hj?file=pages/home/home.ts